# How to set a delay for firing an object

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a code below which will fire an object on to a canvas I created, once a button is pressed (based on different assumptions). However I want there to be a 5 second delay between when the button is pressed and when the object is fired on to the canvas, I'm just not sure where to input this in my code.

I'm assuming I need a setTimeout function, but not sure. I understand the code below won't do anything at the moment, but could anyone tell me where in my code I would need to put the setTimeout function. I have tried in a multitude of places but to no avail.

Thanks.

```js
 trigger = function() {
    reset();

    var effect_size = .8;

    localStorage.setItem("value mac", document.getElementById('demo'));
    localStorage.setItem("direction", direction);

    //var y = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    //const context = y.getContext('2d');
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, y.width, y.height);
    console.log(direction);
    
    console.log ('check????')

    var y = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cir = y.getContext("2d");
    var value_global = document.getElementById('myRange').value;

    console. log(value_global)
    var min_val = (value_global > 1) * ((value_global-1)*.1 - .05);
    if(value_global>1 && value_global<9){
        var range_val = 0.3;
    }else if(value_global==1 || value_global==9){
        var range_val = 0.25;
    }else{
        var range_val = 0.15;
    }
    
    if (direction === 'east') {
      var cen_x = 480-150*value_global/100;
      var cen_y = 300;
      min_val = min_val * effect_size;
    }else if(direction === 'north'){
      var cen_x = 300;
      var cen_y = 70+200*value_global/100;
      min_val = min_val * .2;
    }else if(direction === 'west'){
      var cen_x = 240-150*value_global/100;
      var cen_y = 300;
      min_val = min_val * .2;
    }else if(direction === 'south'){
      var cen_x = 300;
      var cen_y = 322+200*value_global/100;
      min_val = min_val * .2;
    }else{
      alert("Error: Invalid direction.")
    }
    
    cir.globalAlpha = Math.random()*range_val + min_val;

    console.log(cir.globalAlpha)
    
    cir.beginPath();
    cir.arc(cen_x, cen_y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 
    cir.fillStyle = "red";
    cir.fill();
    cir.stroke();

  }
```

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow. Would you mind editing the question to complete the example code? Read also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the thing which needs to be executed after 5 seconds? Is it the whole function trigger? If so, from where is this function called?

Comment: " cir.beginPath();" the delay should begin. This is where the object is fired on to the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portion of code which needs to be delayed should be wrapped inside a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function callback, this way:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    cir.beginPath();
    cir.arc(cen_x, cen_y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    cir.fillStyle = "red";
    cir.fill();
    cir.stroke();
}, 5000)
```

In case the button is clicked twice, then the function will be executed twice. If you want to prevent this (i.e. only run the last timeout), then the timeoutID needs to be stored in a global variable, and `clearTimeout` must be called before calling setTimeout again.

```
let timeoutID

trigger = function() {

    /* ... rest of the code here... */

    if (timeoutID)
        clearTimeout(timeoutID)

    timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        cir.beginPath();
        cir.arc(cen_x, cen_y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        cir.fillStyle = "red";
        cir.fill();
        cir.stroke();
    }, 5000)

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. But thanks for the help. I managed to find a different way around it in the end preventing the button clicking twice but your code in the first part helped me a lot.